# Modernizr, как добавить класс на определенной странице?

Tags: jquery

Есть ли возможность с помощью modernizr добавить класс на определенной странице?
т.е. допустим только на странице page1.html для тега html добавить класс .test

Answer (score 2):

Можно проверять по url'у:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('page1.html') > -1) {
  $('html').addClass('test');
}
```

Comment: ну а в modernizr разве такого функционала нет?

Comment: @word modernizr может добавлять классы в зависимости от поддержки HTML5 и CSS3, но url он определять не умеет